# 504 Gateway Timeout using Application Load Balancer in ECS

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-alb

Deploying a Laravel web application on ECS, in order to enable autoscaling I am using an Application Load Balancer. The application worked (and scaled) perfectly until I introduced a heavy weight page, where I started to get `504 Gateway Timeout` errors after a minute or so.

I am pretty sure the single web server has a higher timeout (this never happens when the application is tested in local) so the problem must be related to something related to AWS environment (ECS / ALB).

Below you can find a snipped of the ALB setting

```
AdminLoadBalancer:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  Properties:
    SecurityGroups:
      - !Ref 'AlbSecurityGroup'
    Subnets:
      - !Ref 'PublicSubnetAz1'
      - !Ref 'PublicSubnetAz2'
    Scheme: internet-facing
  Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'lb']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempts, I solved the issue setting the `idle timeout` attribute of the load balancer, as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout) in theory, because nothing was wrong with the single ECS Tasks. In Cloudformation, it was enough to add the attribute setting of the parameter, and double the default value.

```
AdminLoadBalancer:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: 'idle_timeout.timeout_seconds'
        Value: 120
    SecurityGroups:
      - !Ref 'AlbSecurityGroup'
    Subnets:
      - !Ref 'PublicSubnetAz1'
      - !Ref 'PublicSubnetAz2'
    Scheme: internet-facing
  Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'lb']]
```